# erro ao utilizar django.setup()

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando chamar a função `django.setup()` na versão django. 1.4, vi que foi implementada somente na 1.7.
Existe alguma função parecida com essa que eu possa atualizar, a solução seria só atualizar o django?

Comment: Não lembro desse método `setup()`. O quê você quer fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando utilizar recursos do Django em scripts externos ao framework? Se sim, [esse post aqui](https://www.stavros.io/posts/standalone-django-scripts-definitive-guide/) pode te ajudar.

Mas, tirando alguma necessidade muito específica do seu projeto, o ideal é que você utilize sempre a última versão estável do Django (de qualquer software, na verdade) ou, pelo menos, alguma versão que ainda esteja recebendo atualizações de segurança. A série 1.4 LTS chegou ao fim de vida em primeiro de outubro de 2015, e o recurso que você está buscando realmente só está disponível da versão 1.7 em diante.

[Aqui](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) você pode conferir o cronograma de lançamentos e respectivos períodos de suporte das versões framework.